# How use method from another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Customers < ActiveRecord::Base
  def check_user_name
    ...
    mailto = Emailer.new
    mailto.contact(email, subject='ask', question)
  end
end

class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def contact(email, subject, question, sent_at = Time.now)
  ...
  end
end
```

**CONTROLLER**:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController  
  def ask    
  end

  def check_user    
    cust = Customers.new
    @answer = cust.check_user_name(params[:name], params[:email], params[:question])    
  end

end
```

Have this error:

> NoMethodError in CustomersController#check_user

Comment: Where's the code for the controller?

Comment: Is your `contact` method public? And why are you passing weird parameters like `subject='ask'` ?

Comment: about subject = 'ask' - it's just example. How know is the method public ? :)

Comment: i do this method public. error now
private method `new' called for Emailer:Class

Comment: I think you should have problem with cust.check_user_name method because its not properly defined. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing parameter in the method and the method you have defined in model has no parameter accepting. You should do following:

```
class Customers < ActiveRecord::Base
  def check_user_name(name,email,question)
    mailto = Emailer.new
    mailto.contact(email, subject='ask', question)
  end
end

class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def contact(email, subject, question, sent_at = Time.now)
  end
end
```

Hope above will give you idea and help you.

Comment: still have error:
private method `new' called for Emailer:Class

Comment: you can't create object of mailer. you can directly call the method of Mailer class. Please go through : RailsGuid-> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html and RailsCast-> http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

Comment: ok. I run this command: rails generate mailer UserMailer. then do my code there. and no error...everething fine...but mail was not send...i think, tah because i try to sand mail from local server.

Comment: No, you can send from local server if you have configured well. Please go through the RailsCast episod.